# How to specify the integral type for my enum type like in C#?

Tags: objective-c, enums

In C# I can write something like this:
enum MyEnum : byte { Value1, Value2, Value3 }
and the integral type of MyEnum will be byte.

In Objective-C I want the size of MyEnum to be 1 byte. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it, the underlying type for enums will be chosen for you by the compiler.

If you need specific sizes, use a suitable type (e.g. `uint8_t`) for your variables and make sure the values in the enumeration fit in that types value range.